# Varchar is good for how many length

Tags: mysql

Hello I have a table which has 56 columns among these columns 23 are for longer text I am going to use Varchar(140) for these columns.

Can anybody tell me that is there any problem for using 140 length for the Varchar or not ?

```
............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-count-limit.html

Answer (score 0):

255 characters has often been the maximum length of a VARCHAR in some DBMSes, and sometimes still winds up being the effective maximum if you want to use UTF-8 and have the column indexed.

Comment: i did not get u i m using the values for these columns enlish characters not UTF-8 is it good to use for enlish characters 140 for varchar

Comment: HELLO No one knows the answer